# How to edit MS Access tables via web

Tags: ms-access

I have an MS Access 2007 desktop database that has been in use for many years. Of the numerous tables, I have three tables that now require users to update some fields via the web.  I do not want to move to SQLServer Express, SQLite, MySQL, PostgreSQL... as they are not my skill set.

The scenario is of winning captains entering the score of games on a results form. Users may enter via an iPhone or computer.

My question is what is the best architecture to achieve this end so I can automate the games data from my desktop to the web pages and have any updates appear back on the desktop?

Comment: There are many simple ways to accomplish this.  I'm not sure why you haven't rec'd an answer yet.  It's not clear to me how you plan to host the website.  For light use, MS-Access files work fine with ASP.Net, but if this is not your skillset then you might try the built-in Sharepoint integration features of MS-Access, your need is exactly their purpose -- easy to setup, no special software req'd.  With more info, it will be easier to give you a precise answer.

Comment: For very non-technical web users, I recomment www.formsite.com, won't be realtime, but anyone can set it up and then you import a quick spreadsheet and paste it directly into MS-Access.   Works flawlessly.  Should work well for cell phone input.